# Javeline XSLT example

Tags: javascript, xslt

While browsing the site I saw the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042178/chrome-and-safari-xslt-using-javascript). Reading more on the 
sarissa site I read about Javeline. Would any one have an example of how to perform a transform using Javeline? Also I can not seem to find the following two files:

- javeline_xpath.js
- javeline_xslt.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be aware that Sarrisa is a thin layer to create a single API for XML handling. Underwater it still uses the browsers XML API and could thus still expose browser specific quirks.

It's also a tad outdated as Webkit now offers XSLT support but with some quirks as shown in the linked question.

The Javeline XSLT Compatability script, whilst being a truely great extension, has it's shortcomings too. A major one being that the full xpath 1.0 spectrum is not supported.

You can use it the same way as you would use `XSLTProcessor` [see here](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/howtos.html#transform) make sure you use the correct inclusion sequence though [as shown here](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/howtos.html#javeline).

Answer (score 0):

The javeline site link addressed there is broken. While googling I found these files here :

http://www.blisted.org/export/95/trunk/xmvc/src/js/compat/javeline_xpath.js 
http://www.blisted.org/export/95/trunk/xmvc/src/js/compat/javeline_xslt.js