# Trouble displaying XML file styled by XSLT on Chrome browser

Tags: xml, google-chrome, xslt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can chrome be made to perform an xsl transform on a local file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828898/can-chrome-be-made-to-perform-an-xsl-transform-on-a-local-file)

Taking from this example: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simplexsl.xml

I have two files sitting on my desktop: `simple.xsl` and `simplexsl.xml`, when I open them with Opera, FF4, IE9 and Safari... they come out properly and such. When I use Chrome however... I get a blank page. Help!

(if someone can just copy and paste these and open to see if it works on Chrome 10 for them it would be great!)

`simple.xsl`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->

<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">

    <xsl:for-each select="breakfast_menu/food">

      <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">

        <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></span>

        - <xsl:value-of select="price"/>

      </div>

      <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">

        <xsl:value-of select="description"/>

        <span style="font-style:italic">

          <xsl:value-of select="calories"/> (calories per serving)

        </span>

      </div>

    </xsl:for-each>

  </body>

</html>
```

`simplexsl.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="simple.xsl" ?>

<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->

<breakfast_menu>

    <food>

        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>

        <price>$5.95</price>

        <description>two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>

        <calories>650</calories>

    </food>

    <food>

        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>

        <price>$7.95</price>

        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>

        <calories>900</calories>

    </food>

    <food>

        <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>

        <price>$8.95</price>

        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>

        <calories>900</calories>

    </food>

    <food>

        <name>French Toast</name>

        <price>$4.50</price>

        <description>thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>

        <calories>600</calories>

    </food>

    <food>

        <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>

        <price>$6.95</price>

        <description>two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>

        <calories>950</calories>

    </food>

</breakfast_menu>
```

Comment: duplicate of [Can chrome be made to perform an xsl transform on a local file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3828898/211232)

Comment: It's a known issue that Webkit doesn't honor stylesheet under `file:` protocol. Under `http:` protocol (local server) it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042178/chrome-and-safari-xslt-using-javascript/4252635#4252635)** -- seems that Chrome doesn't support loading of XML files at all.

**Not all XSLT processors support embedded XSLT stylesheets**.

Change your code (this is very easy to do as it only involves adding a top `<xsl:stylesheet>` element and wrapping all the code into an `<xsl:template match="/">` element) to this true XSLT stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
    <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
        <xsl:for-each select="breakfast_menu/food">
            <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
                <span style="font-weight:bold">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                </span>          - 
                <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                <span style="font-style:italic">
                    <xsl:value-of select="calories"/> (calories per serving)          
                </span>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Alright, done but still doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @stockoverflow: As I said in the Update, this seems to be impossible to do with Chrome -- you'll need to use some Javascript to initiate the XSLT transformation.

Comment: Thanks, can I have a link to this Javascript snippet

Comment: [Literal Result Element as stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#result-element-stylesheet) do work in Chrome. Problem is in URI protocol.