# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLElement> has no method 'transformNode'

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

i have written a xsl file which get data from xml file and in another htm file i have written some small script.

code:

```
 if (broadcastMode == 0) {
            xslTarget.innerHTML = Terrestrial.transformNode(TerrestrialStyle.XMLDocument);
        }
```

it is work fine in IE but in google chrome i got this error:

***Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'transformNode'***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use Microsoft-proprietary XSLT code in a non-Microsoft browser, so it doesn't work.

[Here is some information about XSLT in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ).  Chrome seems to have some problems with XSL transformations; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042178/chrome-and-safari-xslt-using-javascript) is a Stackoverflow question with some information.